# Can I Upgrade a CPU from Intel Core i3-2350m 2nd Gen to core i5-2450m 2nd Gen?

Tags: laptop, cpu, lenovo-laptop

I have a laptop equipped with Intel Core i3 2350m 2nd Gen. 
Well, actually my laptop has two different models: the first one with i3 2350m and the second one with i5 2450m.

As I did research on both processors, they both use the same socket and also have the same 35W too as TDP. 
Many websites say i3 2350M is an upgradable CPU.

Can I upgrade my laptop's CPU from i3 2350M to i5 2450M?

CPU World also says the same: http://www.cpu-world.com/Compare/476/Intel_Core_i3_Mobile_i3-2350M_(PGA)_vs_Intel_Core_i5_Mobile_i5-2450M_(BGA).html

My laptop is a Lenovo G570.

Comment: Not sure, maybe this thread has some useful information: https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Lenovo-3000-and-Essential/Lenovo-G570-Processor-Upgrade/td-p/754793

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, so long as you match the socket and generation of the CPUs - and most importantly, that the CPU is not soldered into the laptop and is indeed user serviceable.  In this case, the [Lenovo G570 Service Manual](http://download.lenovo.com/consumer/mobiles_pub/Lenovo%20G470G475G570G575%20Hardware%20Mainenance%20Manual.pdf) does indeed show the CPU is held in place with a locking screw, and can be replaced.

Note that this isn't a trivial task, and requires removal of the fan/heatsink assembly.  Be sure to have some spare thermal paste if you do attempt this.

Comment: Thanks! for this great info. i know hardware stuff for replacing on mobo. and what about i7 2620M? is that possible to replace i3 2350M to i7 2620M?

Comment: @Vaibhav so long as you can obtain it in the PGA socket, that processor should work.  Note, however, that the PGA-version of the i7 2620M has a lower max. temperature of 85C (versus 100C for the i3 and i5 models you've mentioned).  With similar clock speeds, unless you require the larger cache in the i7, I would probably stick with the more inexpensive i5.